# join_buffer_size causes high cpu load

Tags: mysql, query-performance

I am playing and testing with my.cnf and at the moment I have these server specs:

12 CPU vCore
500 GB SSD
24 GB RAM
1 GB Swap

and this is the input of my my.cnf:

```
# GENERAL #
# user                           = mysql
# default-storage-engine         = InnoDB



# DATA STORAGE #
# datadir                        = /var/lib/mysql/


#TIMEOUTS#
wait_timeout                    = 600


#NO DNS#
# skip-name-resolve


# MyISAM #
key-buffer-size                = 32M
myisam-recover                 = FORCE,BACKUP


# SAFETY #
max_connections = 250
# max-allowed-packet             = 16M
# max-connect-errors             = 1000000


# CACHES AND LIMITS #
tmp_table_size = 512M
max_heap_table_size = 512M
join_buffer_size = 384K
query_cache_size = 0
query_cache_type = 0
# thread-cache-size              = 32
# open-files-limit               = 65535
# table-definition-cache         = 4096
# table-open-cache               = 1024


table_definition_cache = -1
performance_schema = ON


# INNODB #
innodb_lock_wait_timeout = 600
innodb_flush_method = O_DIRECT
innodb_buffer_pool_size = 10G
innodb_log_file_size = 1G
innodb_log_buffer_size = 64M
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit = 2
innodb_stats_on_metadata = 0
innodb_buffer_pool_instances = 10
innodb_file_per_table = 1

#LOG QUERIES#
# long_query_time                = 3
# log_slow_queries               = 1
# slow_query_log_file            = /var/lib/mysql/mysql-slow.log


[mysqld]
# Skip reverse DNS lookup of clients
# skip-name-resolve
```

I just made the exprience, that as soon as join_buffer_size exceeds 512k, suddenly the CPU load goes up to 100%. How can this be explained?

Comment: Can you specify which types of CPU time increase (io wait, etc)? Also, does the server swap when you increase join_buffer_size?

Comment: Hey, it is the "cpu:percent-user:value" Value in Plesk. Swap seems ok, it graps about 200 Mb more of the 1 GB swap during this effect. But what goes straight up is the mysql cpu usage and the "Apache an PHP-FPM – Memory usage"

Comment: So it's swapping more than usual, right? And another process is increasing its CPU time too. So I would think that, with that setting, MySQL is consuming too much memory, and than MySQL and PHP compete to use the available memory, causing CPU waits. Also note that MySQL should always run on a dedicated machine to avoid this and other problems.

Answer (score 0):

Please try the experiment again; this time capture these for the two values of `join_buffer_size`:

```
 EXPLAIN SELECT ... (including the query)
 how long the query took
 SHOW CREATE TABLE ...  -- of reach table in the query
```

Meanwhile, I will *guess* at this explanation.  The Optimizer has several ways it might perform a query.

- Ignore the join_buffer and use lookups (indexed or not) for joining.
- Use the join_buffer:  Load the second table completely into a hash in RAM, then reach into it for lookups.

The *potential* problem include

- The Optimizer may not have the "right" statistics for deciding between the two choices.  (There is no reliable way to fix this for all cases.)
- There may be a `LIMIT` or something else that makes loading the entire table the "wrong" approach.
- Once the join_buffer is loaded, the rest of the query is CPU-bound.  When not using the join_buffer, the query may be I/O-bound and is likely to take longer (elapsed time).  (Hence my request for the timings.)
- Etc.